# jQuery - Scrolling down and add overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this button, when I click it, I want to add a class to a DIV with an ID. After that, it should scroll to the bottom of the page.

I have this currently:

```
  $("#signUp").click(function() {
$("#overlay").addClass(".overlay");       
 $('html, body').animate({scrollBottom:0}); 

    });
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="big-signup"> <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="signUp"><button>Sign up now. It's <span>FREE &raquo;</span></button></a><br /> <br />
```

And the css:

```
#overlay{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
.overlay{
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Currently I can't get the code to do anything. Nothing happens when I click the button..

UPDATE: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P23P5/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show a sample in jsfiddle.net ?
or use firebug to understand what error exactly is coming up..

Comment: I checked the firebug console, it doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addClass method is expecting the name of the class without any dot:

```
$("#overlay").addClass("overlay");
```

The code that usually I use to scroll the page to a specific position is:

```
var target = $(window).height(); // Y value
var animationSelector='html:not(:animated)';

// Fix for Safari
if($.browser.safari) {animationSelector='body:not(:animated)';}
// Animate
$(animationSelector).animate({scrollTop: target}, 400, 'swing');
```

Comment: The css class .overlay should have:
display:block!important;

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$("#signUp").click(function() {
$("#overlay").addClass(".overlay");       
 $('html, body').animate({scrollBottom:0});     
    });

}) ;
```

Basically, apply the click event after the page have rendered

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are adding the class `.overlay` and not `overlay`.

Secondly, you are not showing the `id="overlay"` div prior to adding the class.

Thirly, you need to give the overlay div either a fixed or absolute position.